# Removing values from a variable that start with a certain string

Tags: string, powershell, active-directory, startswith

I am working on a script that will copy over one user's group memberships to another user, but I need to exclude any groups that start with `R-`. I do not want to remove any groups that simply contain `R-` in the name, i.e. "CPR-Training" I would want to keep, but "R-Confidential" I would want to remove. I have tried using `.StartsWith("R-")` but I cannot convert the output of this into a remove mechanic.

What I have is:

```
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Id <FirstUser> | select Name
$RMV = $Groups.Name.StartsWith("R-")
```

but from there I do not know how to take the groups that start with `R-` and remove them from `$Groups`. It would be something like `$Groups.Name.Remove($RMV)` but `StartsWith()` just evaluates to true/false and not the group name.

From there I would apply the updated `$Groups` to the second user. That part I have.

I have ready many similar questions and threads on several different sites, but none did quite what I am looking for. All the solutions I could find would remove any groups that contained `R-` instead of only those that start with `R-`.

tl;dr I can't figure out how to go through `$groups` and remove all string values that start with `R-`.

Comment: You might find [`Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) to be useful.

Comment: I feel like I am getting closer. I can get the group names singled out now with:
$raw = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -id <firstUser> | select name 

foreach($script in $raw){if ($script.name.startswith("R-"))
{$group = $raw -replace $script, ""}}

When I do a write-host $Script it displays only the R- groups by name. So I  am left trying to figure out how to take that value and replace it with ""

Comment: I have also tried

$raw = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -id <firstUser> | select name 
foreach($script in $raw){if ($script -match "^R-")
{$group = $raw -replace $script, ""}}

Write-Host $group

And what I am finding is that it will remove the very last entry that matches "R-"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Id <FirstUser> |
          Where-Object {-not ($_.Name.StartsWith("R-"))} |
          select Name
```

Comment: Alternatively you could use `$_.Name -notlike 'R-*'`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the scripts I tried were actually working. The group being left behind has a white space at the beginning. So it was not matching the "R-" even though it looked like it did.